# CMD - If exists <file>

Tags: redirect, if-statement, cmd, exists

The below commands (with debug lines added - indented) should only redirect the echo's output to a file, should it already exist, according to my understanding.

However, it would seem that `if exist %test0%` *always* fills the file (creating it if non-existant) with the echo's output.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
@echo off
type test.bat
set test0="e:\documents and settings\administrator\desktop\test.log"
   echo.&echo.
   if exist %test0% (echo !!Exists!!) else (echo !!Doesn't Exist!!)
(if exist %test0% echo.&echo.&echo -------------------------------------------------&echo.&echo.)>>%test0%
```

[image]

And the file gets created(!)

[image]



**EDIT:** This above was a simplified example, and unfortunately [MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15416) answer doesn't help me solve the full command (I had hoped it would). The full one line if statement is:
`if exist %test0% (echo.&echo.&echo -------------------------------------------------&echo.&echo.) else (set /p .=<nul)>>%test0%&set errorlevel=0||set errorlevel=1`

How would I have whichever condition of the `if` matched output to the file (Hopefully with only one reference to the file, i.e., not one in each `if` conditional), and have the `errorlevel` set based on the `exist`ance of the file?

Could anyone help with the actual full command issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should ***never*** set ERRORLEVEL directly. That name is reserved for reporting on the results of the prior command. When you set the value directly, you override the intended functionality and it ceases to expand to the actual ERRORLEVEL, it expands to the value you set instead. That can break all kinds of code.

You can force the ERRORLEVEL to a value by running a command with known result, redirecting output to nul if necessary: `ver >nul` sets ERRORLEVEL to 0, `set /p .=<nul` sets ERRORLEVEL to 1.

You can force the ERRORLEVEL to any particular value of your choosing by using `cmd /c exit /b N`, where `N` is an integral value.

You also have faulty logic. Your IF command succeeds (has no error) regardless whether the condition evaluates to TRUE or FALSE. If you want to set the ERRORLEVEL, then you need to do it within your parenthesized blocks.

There is nothing wrong with putting everything on one line, but I find the code easier to read when using multiple lines for complex statements like yours. I believe the following is what you are looking for.

```
if exist %test0% (
  echo.
  echo.
  echo -------------------------------------------------
  echo.
  echo.
  ver >nul
) >>%test0% else (
  set /p .=<nul
)
```

***Edit in response to comments***

Not much change needed.

```
if exist %test0% (
  (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo -------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    echo.
    set ERR=0
  ) >>%test0%
) else (
  copy nul %test0%
  set ERR=1
)
```

Comment: I realise this is the third time I have moved the goal post, so to say, but `errorlevel` is not the actual variable name (Thought this may be a bad idea, but makes for easier reading than the real var name - Thanks for the reminder though). As for `set /p .=<nul` that is interesting, and explains some logic I couldn't understand, but am actually using this to only create the file, if it doesn't already exist, but not fill it with anything. Lastly I think there is a misunderstanding so I will post another comment outlining my goals.

Comment: 1) Create a file with nothing in it, if file doesn't already exist; or fill it with _double blank lines+line of dashes+double blank lines_ if it does (Preferably with only one `>>file` directive, not one in each if condition). 2) Set a variable or `%errorlevel%` depending on the success of the redirection.

Comment: Thanks, so first one seems to satisfy both conditions; Second one always creates (or amends) the file with the blank lines + dashes, but never just creates an empty file, even if non-existing prior to running. However, am curious, in terms of the second example, is there no way to have either the true or false conditional output to the file, does it have to be just one of them, or who two stated redirects?

Comment: @user66001 - Did you actually run the 2nd edited code? The append redirection will create the empty file if it does not exist.

Comment: [Batch file contents](http://i.imgur.com/wu0zncR.png) & the [New file produced contents](http://i.imgur.com/BAfhCC3.png) that always has the blank lines + dashes in it, every time run after deleting the .log file.

Comment: @user66001 - Oops - you are correct. My logic was bad. I fixed the 1st edited option and removed the 2nd.

Comment: Okay, that works, however I added `>nul` to the end of `copy nul %test0%`. As for the 2nd Goal, I suppose I can just put in `if %errorlevel%`'s to catch redirection problems. Just to make sure, is there no way to specify the redirection only once, rather than in each conditional, which flows on to checking each redirect in each conditional separately also. Was sort of hoping that there could be a single redirect at the end of the `if` block, and therefore a single check if the redirect was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Check your parentheses. `(x) >> output.log` redirects the output of `x` to `output.log`. That means the redirection happens regardless of what the output is, and in particular always creates the file.

Now if you'd write `if Y (echo Text >> output.log)` the redirection would be conditional on `Y`, and might not happen.

**[edit]**
With the question as it's worded now, the simple solution seems to be:

1. Set `%ERRORLEVEL%` based on `exist %test0%`. No redirection has happened at this point.
2. Use `%ERRORLEVEL%` to determine what to do. You can change `%test0%` without altering `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

BTW, [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)

Comment: Thanks MSalters - I had thought that the `if` statement wouldn't parse the `echo`'s if `exist` didn't return true, ergo no output to send to file (Though accept the file may have been created empty). I actually simplified the question, so if I could ask how to make the following (adjusted with my best guess, based on your answer, which doesn't work), `if exist %test0% ((echo.&echo.&echo -------------------------------------------------&echo.&echo.) else (echo.))>>%test0%` that would be appreciated.